# Current selected value in DataGridView using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to get the current selected value from a DataGridView

```
MessageBox.Show(""+dataGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString()+"")
```

but it never shows the selected value.

It shows

> System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection

Answer (score 2):

you should do it this way

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGrdiView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString());
```

try to access Value or Text of a single cell, and not the entire collection

you can also iterate through the entire `SelectedCells` collection

```
 string text;
 foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
 {
     //MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString());
     text +=cell.Value.ToString();
 }
 MessageBox.Show(text);
```

Comment: SelectedCells in winforms is collection of DataGridViewCell, and it does have .Value property.

Comment: I wrote that either. But are you sure that's the case for WinForms either? I checked it only in WPF, there you're right. `DataGridCellInfo` indeed has no `Value` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
string message = string.Empty;
foreach (var c in _dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
    message += " " + c.Value.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it always a single cell selected you could just use. dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].tostring. The reason you are getting the class name ia because you are getting back a collection of selected cells as their couls be more than one cell selected at a time.